# How to design a database for modular widgets

Tags: database, database-design

I'm really stumped and hoping all you smart people out there can help me!

My knowledge of database design is middle of the road at best.  Just good enough to get me in trouble really.  I'm a programmer first and foremost.

I'm trying to build a website and the design of the back-end database has got me stumped.

I'm going to give a somewhat contrived example here for the sake of explanation, but this example is spot on with what I need to achieve.

Image for a minute that you were building a database for old school fans of the game Car Wars, or something similar.  In this game the player can pick one of several base cars, and then customize it for use in the game.

There are some attributes that every base car would have for the player to customize, such as the engine, transmission, and armor.  Every car has these slots, and player's can drop the appropriate items into these slots.  In addition to these common slots, each car has N number of mounts.  This varies per car, though every car has at least one, and a large car could have a dozen or more.  Players can place weapons, or utility items into these mounts.  Once the player has configured their car, it is saved as a build.  That build essentially defines, the base car they chose, their choices for engine, transmission, and armor, as well as what weapons and items they placed into each mount.  This is their personalized build.

At the first level, the table layout is pretty simple.  This is what I currently have:

There is a CAR table that contains fields for basic stats on the car, as well as fields to indicate what it can support for engine, transmission, and armor.  (For example a small car might only support a v4 engine and light armor, while a large car might support a v8 and heavy plating).

ENGINE, TRANSMISSION, and ARMOR tables which define all the available choices for the player for those items.

There is a MOUNTS table that defines the size of the mount, what CAR it belongs to, and where on the CAR it is physically located.

And of course a WEAPONS table, and ITEMS table, defining the weapons and items that can go into the mounts, as well as data such as size for control over what can go into what mount.

This is the first layer and it all works well.  The problem is the second layer, defining how all these connect in the case of a saved BUILD.  I just can't figure out how to connect all the dots between CAR, MOUNT, and WEAPONS/ITEMS in those mounts in the context of a saved build.

In the BUILD table, I can have it point to the base car, and the choices for engine, transmission, and armor easy enough. Storing what weapons/items they chose though becomes a bit more tricky.  Even if I ignore for the moment that I need to know which mount each is placed into, the fact remains that I could have N number of weapons/items  mounted.  Each build would have a variable amount.  So I have a One(Build) to Many(Weapons) relationship but how would I define that relationship without making a unique instance of a weapon or item for each build?  Then of course there is the added complexity of the fact that I need to store not only what weapons and items the player chooses, but also which specific mount they put them into.

Now I could probably work my way out of this mess if I create duplicate instances of each weapon or item, with that extra instance pointing the the build it belongs in, and the mount is is stored in, but to do that means for every build I need to essentially create duplicates of every weapon or item chosen, and this seems totally stupid and wasteful.

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem.  I'm either just being blind and missing it, or my lack of experience with database design prevents me from seeing what I need to see.  So pretend you all are Obi Wan Kenobi and your my only hope!

I'll be sure to edit this to provide further details if any are requested.  Thanks!

EDIT: Not sure why it would matter, but for the sake of complete information I am using django for my website so the DB is abstracted away.  I use SQLite locally for development, but the live server uses MySQL.

Comment: So apparently the process of typing all this out, collecting my thoughts, and summarizing everything for the question, enabled me to see what I was missing.  I feel really stupid now, but all I was missing is that I need an additional table that simply defines the relationship between weapon to mount to build.

Comment: sounds right.  you should post your comment as an answer.  in a few days you can mark it as correct.  you don't get any points, but it closes the question, which will make your profile look better (people are more likely to answer future questions if you have closed previous ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional table whose purpose is to define the link between items, mounts, and builds.

Each entry in the BUILDLINK table would be an item id, mount id, and the id of a build it belongs to.  This would be a many to one relationship with the BUILD table.